# Avocado roots growing in the wrong direction

Tags: plant-health, roots, avocado, growing-medium

My roots are growing from all sides, including the roots wrapping around to the top. I left town, they where in a napkin. What may I do to help them grow, or did I mess up? Both sides are growing around to the top.

For now I’ll keep them in napkins. I know its wrong, but I don't know what to do and they have been alive while growing in the napkins.[image]!![image][image][image][image]

Comment: Please take the [tour] and browse through the [help]: all questions *and answers* should be posted here. **Do not post your personal data, including your e-mail here.** That said, you should use the [edit] function and add a photo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're probably fine. If you post a picture (I don't remember how much reputation one needs to post pictures, so apologies) but if the roots are healthy and they don't extend past 4-5 inches, it won't be an issue when it comes to transplanting them to a pot of soil. Tangled roots can become a problem if several plants are tangled together or are bunched up. A young tree can over come quite a lot, follow advice for a proper seedling care and you shouldn't expect problems.

You asked 'how do I undo this' - if you're trying to do something ornamental with the roots, I can't help. If you're trying to have a bit of fun growing an avocado, then you should keep going! Plant the seed with the top-of-the-egg side up (or if it's not shaped like that, the end where the root doesn't exit the pit) in soil a little further than trusted advice would suggest. This depends on the seed size, maybe 3-4 inches (7-10 cm) below the top of the soil and be patient!